# Is size Q equal to size SHA(Q)?

Tags: hash, public-key, elliptic-curves

Assume d is a 128 bit random integer and P is base point of an elliptic curve and Q = dP is a point on the elliptic curve and SHA is a hash function with 128 bit output, my question is:
Is size Q equal to size SHA(Q)?
If not, then wich is smaller size?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475049/is-size-q-equal-to-size-shaq

Comment: "The elliptic curve" is undefined, and very relevant. "Size (of) Q" can have several interpretations, for there are several means to define a point on an elliptic curve. No hash form the SHA family is 128-bit.

Comment: Suppose we take only 128-bits out of 160-bits output in SHA-1 hash function.

Comment: @star Consider this: what if we replace "elliptic curve" in your question with a different finite field, for example the ring of integers modulo _n_. Do you still think your question can be answered? Don't you think we'd need more information, for example the modulus?

Answer (score 1):

This was answered in the Comments of the math.stackex:

> Recall SHA-1 produces a 'fixed length' output, regardless of input, of a 160-bits. For elliptic curves, we could have the points (0,0) all the way up to two 128-bit points (P,Q) if that is your underlying field size. So, you need to be able to handle points that can be as large as 128-bits, but those can be representing integers equal to 0 all the way up to 128-bits. In other words, Q can be zero, but SHA(Q) is 160-bits. Also, I suppose you meant Q to be one of the points (x,y) on the elliptic curve. – [Amzoti](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/38839/amzoti)

Meaning no, they're not equal SHA-1 is larger.